# Can one say "I swear on my mother's grave" when their mother is alive?

Tags: phrases

I am not entirely sure this is the correct forum to ask this question, but here I go nonetheless.

I was talking to somebody the other day and they said "I swear on my mother's grave" to reinforce the truthfulness of a story. However, a few minutes later, while on a different subject, they said "...I was talking to my mom yesterday and she said....". That struck me as inconsistent with that mother's grave statement.

My question is, generally speaking, does the usage of "I swear on my mother's grave" imply that your mother is no longer alive? Or is it perfectly appropriate to use regardless?

Comment: You need a good memory to be a liar.

Comment: This is a theological question not an English language one. The rules of English grammar don't say what you can swear an oath on, or what happens when you break an oath, swear an invalid oath, or swear an oath you have no intention of keeping. There seem to be some relevant questions on the Christianity and Islam Stack Exchanges, possibly for other religions too.

Comment: Obviously, she would have to be dead., Live people don't have graves. (I can't believe I had to write that.} And this is not religious. It's logical.

Comment: clearly the person used this as an expression, not literally

Comment: Your mother doesn't have a grave if she is still alive. So it's not used accurately. Not that we have to use expressions accurately all the time. This also is not a religious issue. Graves may have spiritual implications, but they are physical objects.

Comment: @StuartF I appreciate the comment. I simply did not know where to ask this one.

Comment: I don't see a logical reason one can't swear on something that is expected to exist in the future but does not yet exist, and "swear on my mother's grave" is so common as to approach a set phrase which might not be used literally anyway. As for StuartF's concern, the Bible advises against oaths altogether, so probably Christianity won't be a fruitful angle.

Comment: Touchstone in [*As You Like It* (1.2.)](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/asyoulikeit/asyoulikeit.1.2.html) argues that "if you swear by that that is not, you are not forsworn," no matter what falsehood you may thus swear to. And when [Chesterton](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/57420/elegy-in-a-country-churchyard) laments that "those who rule in England . . . have no graves as yet," it is indeed a trope for their still being alive. But finally I think the oath on the mother's grave is to be laughed off as jocose.

Comment: @Casey "and "swear on my mother's grave" is so common as to approach a set phrase which might not be used literally anyway". And that is why I thought maybe giving the benefit of a doubt would be appropriate. Still, it seems the majority of the people I ask appear to understand the phrase as implying that your mother is no longer alive.

Comment: Unless you think she is somehow trying to deceive you (and doing a damned sloppy job at it), then that's just evidence for the claim.

Comment: This is a common trope in TV shows, movies, etc.: The dishonest character swears on his (living) mother’s grave. A web search quickly turned up [an example from the sitcom Punky Brewster](https://www.sitcomsonline.com/boards/showthread.php?t=317449), for example.

Comment: You can say "... or I'll eat my hat" without owning a hat. There isn't a law against it.

Comment: I've occasionally heard people say something along the lines of "I swear on my still-living mother's future grave". I think that's what most people mean if they use the set expression you quoted. The mothers in question may not appreciate it much though.